# Elasticsearch, filter for accents

Tags: elasticsearch

So, while [asciifolding](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/asciifolding-tokenfilter.html) would turn `è` into `e` it won't filter out a single accent like `` ` ``, right? So how can I get rid of them? For example I want to index `` O`Learys `` and be able to search for any variation of `olearys`, `O learys`, `` o`learys ``.

Comment: That should be the job for the WordDelimiterFilterFactory, check it out.

Comment: I did look at [that](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) but wouldn't that split it up to ```o``` and ```learys``` and therefore not match ```olearys``` ?

Comment: Ok, so I tried WordDelimiter, but as I expected it won't match ```olearys``` but it will match ```o learys``` & ```learys```.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can achieve what you want in a single step. If you have a look at what you index through the analyze api you can see it yourself. I'd use a multi_field in order to index the field in different ways (different word_delimiter settings) and then search on all field variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to make `` O`Learys `` to match both `olearys` and `O learys` at the same time using analyzers, tokenizers or filters that come with elasticsearch. It would require to detect presence of `` ` `` and indexing `` O`Learys `` twice: first as one token `olearys` and then as two tokens `o` `learys`. It can be done by writing  only with a custom token filter though.

As a workaround, you can make both `olearys` and `` o`learys `` to match `` O`Learys `` by removing character `` ` `` from the input using [Mapping Char Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/mapping-charfilter.html).

Comment: Thanks! that worked great, it actually matched ```o learys``` too because I already had an n-gram filter in the analyzer.